# Installing Linux/Ubuntu on XBOX 360

Tags: linux, xbox360

Is it possible to change the XBOX 360 operating system to any popular flavor of Linux? I recently read it was possible to do this but the XBOX 360 seems to have barriers to prevent people from doing this. Does anyone have any first hand experience doing this so you can assist me?

Comment: First google hit for "xbox 360 linux": http://www.free60.org/Main_Page. Probably some of the others are worth checking out too.

Comment: @terdon Have done that, but no one conclusively confirmed anything, have not seen any Ubuntu or Fedora installation on XBOX 360. Rather, all I have seen is "XBOX 360 HAS ADDED SECURITY" !

Comment: Sorry but googling "xbox 360 ubuntu" returns a nice [tutorial](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=400945) and various [videos](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_pEHBHbUp8Q) of it working. I meant no offense, it just seems that you didn't really look around before asking here. We frown on that :(.

Comment: @terdon I was looking for first hand experience, apologies if I came across as rude. I will close this question ASAP. Sorry once again.

Comment: Hey, no worries, you were not rude at all. The free60 site has three different howtos for Ubuntu.

Comment: @terdon I have got voted down -3, I guess it is only fair to close this question.

Comment: I hate the word hack.... with a passion.

Comment: @Griffin Lets say, it is a form of art ! may be a dark one !

Comment: @Arkapravo No it is a overused word that is almost always used improperly. This is a very good example of that.

Comment: @Griffin I agree with your revision ! However, I do not have 2K points to approve it !

Comment: It will be approved later then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible. There is a project, [the Free60 project](http://www.free60.org/Main_Page) which aims towards getting Linux onto the 360.

> Free60 is a project towards porting GNU/Linux, BSD, Darwin and related
>   open-source operating systems to the Microsoft Xbox 360 video game
>   console.

It depends on what type of system you have. Zephyr, Falcon, Jasper and Trinity systems are vulnerable via the [Reset Glitch Hack](http://www.free60.org/Reset_Glitch_Hack).

Consoles manufactured before 16-06-2009 which are running a Kernel equal to or lower than 2.0.7371.0 are vulnerable via the [SMC hack](http://www.free60.org/SMC_Hack).